# Linking against Apple frameworks with gcc

Tags: gcc, core-audio, macos-carbon

I've created some wrapper functions that encapsulate working with CoreAudio, and the goal is to create a C library that I can use with some command line C++ tools.  So far things are working well.  I took a sample project, modified it, and it builds and runs in XCode.  I'd like to skip XCode altogether and build the library with gcc and a Makefile.

How can I link against an Apple Framework?  Are Frameworks just shared libraries that I could include in the -l and -L options on gcc?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here's an example:

> `gcc -framework CoreServices -o test test.c`

From the man page of Apple's gcc (i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1):

```
   In addition to the options listed below, Apple's GCC also accepts and
   passes nearly all of the options defined by the linker ld and by the
   library tool libtool.  Common options include -framework, -dynamic,
   -bundle, -flat_namespace, and so forth.  See the ld and libtool man
   pages for further details.
```

And from ld's man page:

```
 -framework name[,suffix]
             This option tells the linker to search for `name.frame-
             work/name' the framework search path.  If the optional suffix
             is specified the framework is first searched for the name
             with the suffix and then without (e.g. look for `name.frame-
             work/name_suffix' first, if not there try `name.frame-
             work/name').
```

Comment: So the difference between linking with `-framework` and linking with `-l` on Mac OS is the search path right?