# How to link to the carbon with gcc in mac?

Tags: c++, macos, macos-carbon

I develope an application in mac that uses carbon.

My IDE is Code::Blocks (GCC compiler). My code compiles successfully but does not link.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Carbon/Carbon.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //CGEventFlags flags = CGEventSourceFlagsState(1);

    while(true)
    {
        CGEventSourceStateID eventSource = kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState;
        bool b = CGEventSourceKeyState(eventSource, kVK_Command) && CGEventSourceKeyState(eventSource, kVK_ANSI_Period);
        if(b)
        {
            cout << "Yes" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "No" << endl;
        }
    }

    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How to link to the carbon with gcc in mac?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple `-framework Carbon` flag for gcc should do the trick, according to various sources around the internet.

Cannot verify this, though.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780133/linking-against-apple-frameworks-with-gcc) seems slightly similar.

Comment: Seems like including Carbon.h from a C++ program will now fail to compile on mac os 10.10 with gcc. Any work around?

Comment: @mangledorf that is both irrelevant and rather impossible for me to answer. Ask a new question with more detail than that and/or look for a solution elsewhere